# How to get the difference of each qty of 2 django table?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have here 2 different Django Models.

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qty = models.FloatField()

class Sold(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    qty = models.FloatField()
```

How to get the difference of each qty ? For example : `Stocks.qty - Sold.qty`

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should reconsider redesigning your database in order to make queries like this easier.

For example, the most simple (but not the most feature-complete) solution:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

And just add to or remove from the quantity field whenever you have a stock movement event:

```
item = Item.objects.get(name="Chair")
item.update(quantity=item.quantity - 1)
item.save()
```

Then it's really easy to get an Item's quantity.

```
item = Item.objects.get(name="Chair")
print(item.quantity)
```

There are Django / database features that make stuff like this a bit nicer, but as it seems that you are beginner, this is how I'd recommend you approach this for the time being, until you find your footing.